# How to mock InputFile (csv) in Blazor while unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, blazor

I am using `InputFile` in Blazor to accept csv files from user.
While doing testing I want to either give a physical file to `InputFile` or I want to mock a CSV file and do the testing.

I created a mock as below but I don't know how to give `Name`,mock data(in file) to this mock:

`var mockIbrowser = new Mock<IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile>>();`

Actual Test Case:

```
[Fact]
        public void FileUploadTest()
        {
            using var ctx = new TestContext();
            var mockIbrowser = new Mock<IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile>>();
            
            var optionsMock = Substitute.For<IOptions<RemoteBrowserFileStreamOptions>>();
            ctx.Services.AddSingleton<IOptions<RemoteBrowserFileStreamOptions>>(optionsMock);
            ctx.JSInterop.SetupVoid("Blazor._internal.InputFile.init", x => true);
            //Arrange
            var comp = ctx.RenderComponent<FileProcess>();
            //expected
            string expectedMarkupButton = @"<button type=""submit"" class=""btn btn-outline-primary"" @btnstatus>Upload Selected File(s)</button>";
            string expectedMarkupMsg = @"<h3 style=""color:Black;"">All Tasks performed successfully</h3>";
            //Action
            comp.Find("InputFile").Click();
            comp.Find("form").Submit();
            //Matched ?
            comp.Find("button").MarkupMatches(expectedMarkupButton);
            comp.Find("h3").MarkupMatches(expectedMarkupMsg);
        }
```